# Spotify-nonify.py script doesn`t work in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: scripts, notification, spotify

When I was on Ubuntu 12.10 I was using [spotify-notify](https://code.google.com/p/spotify-notify/).py script which make spotify compatible with media buttons and there is a notifications showing when playing a song

but on Ubuntu 13.04 is no longer working is there any package missing or any solution that make that script working again

[click here to download the script file](https://spotify-notify.googlecode.com/files/spotify-notify-v0.6d.zip)

Comment: Have you installed both dependences that Spotify-notify indicates on Google Code?

sudo apt-get install notify-osd python-indicate

Comment: Leopoldo Pla thank you it works now after installing notify-osd python-indicate

Comment: I'll post it as it helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you didn't installed both dependences that Spotify-notify indicates on Google Code:

```
sudo apt-get install notify-osd python-indicate
```

Comment: I used the comments and I solved the question, that's why I posted the same comment as a answer. I edited my answer to show as a real answer and not as a the comment I posted.